# What part of code increases memory usage?

Tags: c++, qt, memory

I have a server application (with QTcpServer ).
VLD memory leak check shows no memory leaks.
but when I send commands from client to server , Task Manager shows memory increment.
so , server will run out of memory.
How can I find tha parts of code that cause such problem ?
thanks

Comment: `malloc()` and `operator new` are particularly good at allocating memory, especially when paired with the lack of `free()` and `delete`, respectively.

Comment: Most of Qt objects have parent objects. any object , deletes it's children. so no memory leak is shown. but some where in code , some parent object stays alive while server is running and just gets deleted when server closes. therefore , memory increases.

Comment: "some parent object stays alive while server is running and just gets deleted when server closes" You mean **you** don't delete it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Fill out this questions and I think I'll be able to help you:

- Memory increases when client connects? Y/N
- Memory decreases when client disconnects? Y/N
- After 3 client connect/disconnect, you're at idle, did the memory increase?
- Connect with 1 client, send commands, and disconnect. Did the memory increase?

If the last was YES, try to isolate the command that makes the memory increase.
If all commands are increasing memory usage, then the code that handles the command dispatch is leaking.
If only 1 command is leaking, then that command is leaking.

General questions:

- do you specify a parent to each Qt object you allocate using `new` and that you don't free with `delete`? If not, that's your leak.
- do you use QList or QHashMap ? If yes check that your clear/tidy them when needed

At the very last, you could try and use the [HP Garbage collector](http://www.hpl.hp.com/personal/Hans_Boehm/gc/) on the non-QT objects that you allocate.

Comment: Thank you. I don't create all Qt objects with only one parent. But you are right , I should specify if one command is leaking , or all command. I think I should track the code line by line. thanks again.

Answer (score 2):

When doing some "work" while accepting a client obviously your memory usage will grow. What is important is that when you are done with the "work" you free the objects that you allocated. If these are QObject derived objects Qt will track and delete them at program exit so indeed, there will be no memory leaks shown, but if you don't delete them while your server is up and running, they will just stay there.

You can do a few things to decrease your memory usage, such as do not create objects on the heap, but on the stack (these objects will go away automatically) try to use as less as possible memory allocations, free the allocated memory immediately you don't need it, etc...

Maybe by sharing some code (if it's not extremely huge) will help us to identify a few points we can improve on regarding memory usage.

Comment: Yes. and thanks. I know and accept what u say. Now , is there any tool to use for such problem?